# Using roscpp in existing app on Android/iOS

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
I have an existing app, or rather a shared library, that I compile for mobile platforms (currently Android, but iOS will come very soon too). It is a C++ library that have heavy dependencies (“heavy” in terms of cross-compiling and amount of code).
Now, I need to publish (and consume) some ROS topics. I was looking at [ROS client libraries page](http://wiki.ros.org/Client%20Libraries) and it seems to me that I should use roscpp for my project.
However, after following through all the [android ndk tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk) I’m still confused on how I would incorporate roscpp into my existing code.
I would expect to have a set of .so or .a libraries compiled for the target platform (btw, I use arm64 while docker container compiles for arm7) and a headers folder to include in my source code.
My question is – how can I use roscpp in my existing C++ android library? I am not using Android studio, I use ndk-build directly.
I noticed there’re Application.mk and Android.mk files in “roscpp_android_ndk” folder, is that shall be used ultimately?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338249/using-roscpp-in-existing-app-on-android/ios/) by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-11-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2019-11-21**:
Could you elaborate a bit more on your hardware setup? Are you running ROS on a robot and you want to read /publish topics from it from Android/iOS? Or you want to actually run ROS nodes on Android/iOS?

**Comment by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) on 2019-11-21**:
ROS runs on multple [OpenPTrack](http://openptrack.org/) machines. My mobile client needs to publish specific topics that will be consumed by a ROS node. Mobile client will also need to subscribe for few topics.
I have a c++ library that I NDK-compile and incorporate in mobile application in a third-party framework (not a Java/Swift app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to successfully compile roscpp for Android using this [repo](https://github.com/Intermodalics/ros_android). It is a fork of the repo from the [tutorial](https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android.git) but most recent one (dated April 2019).
Once libraries are compiled, I added this `Android.mk` to glue them into a static library and use it in my project:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

stlibs := xmlrpcpp Bullet3Geometry  boost_stacktrace_basic  diagnostic_aggregator  pcl_recognition  orocos-bfl  yaml-cpp  bz2  boost_math_tr1  charset  amcl_sensors  base_local_planner  theoraenc  vorbisfile  orocos-kdl  opencv_imgcodecs3  opencv_xobjdetect3  opencv_videoio3  SDLmain  tf2  boost_signals  image_publisher  SDL_image  image_proc  opencv_reg3  xml2  camera_calibration_parsers  move_base  boost_container  joint_state_listener  boost_context  bondcpp  boost_math_c99f  camera_info_manager  opencv_calib3d3  boost_math_c99l  navfn  tinyxml2  pcl_io_ply  boost_iostreams  opencv_xfeatures2d3  opencv_stereo3  urdfdom_world  boost_thread  eigen_conversions  boost_program_options  roslib  boost_coroutine  pcl_common  opencv_xphoto3  PocoNet  boost_timer  Bullet3Dynamics  opencv_ml3  boost_contract  ogg  opencv_plot3  collada-dom2.4-dp  tf  rosbag_storage  opencv_rgbd3  boost_type_erasure  interactive_markers  boost_log_setup  tinyxml  boost_atomic  flann_cpp_s-gd  pcl_search  laser_geometry  boost_random  pcl_ros_surface   boost_date_time  opencv_structured_light3  urdf  theora  opencv_optflow3  params  qhullcpp  uuid  pcl_surface  map_server_image_loader  rosconsole_backend_interface  urdfdom_model  LinearMath  tf2_ros  Bullet3OpenCL_clew  vorbisenc  pcl_features  pluginlib_tutorials  tf_conversions  opencv_fuzzy3  pcl_registration  opencv_saliency3  boost_test_exec_monitor  theoradec  boost_stacktrace_noop   opencv_img_hash3  opencv_ccalib3  boost_system  PocoUtild  opencv_tracking3  opencv_superres3  opencv_core3  lz4  opencv_surface_matching3  pointcloud_filters  roscpp_serialization  opencv_phase_unwrapping3  compressed_image_transport  compressed_depth_image_transport  move_slow_and_clear  PocoXML  assimp  pcl_kdtree  PocoJSON  opencv_aruco3  cpp_common console_bridge rosconsole_bridge pcl_ros_filters  opencv_ximgproc3  pcl_io  opencv_bgsegm3  boost_exception  pcl_sample_consensus  layers  Bullet3Collision  BulletCollision  robot_state_publisher_solver  opencv_imgproc3  depth_image_proc  rosbag  pcl_filters  stereo_image_proc  octomap  pcl_segmentation  opencv_video3  pcl_stereo  rosconsole_android  boost_math_c99  kdl_conversions  boost_prg_exec_monitor  opencv_dnn3  opencv_line_descriptor3  image_transport_plugins  amcl_map  opencv_objdetect3  pcl_octree  polled_camera  boost_math_tr1l  boost_math_tr1f  voxel_grid  flann_cpp_s  qhullstatic_r  actionlib  boost_wave  PocoUtil  opencv_bioinspired3  image_geometry  theora_image_transport  opencv_text3  kdl_parser  urdfdom_sensor  Bullet3Common  pcl_ros_tf  opencv_highgui3  costmap_2d  opencv_dpm3  Bullet2FileLoader  carrot_planner  nodeletlib  BulletSoftBody  pcl_keypoints  pcl_ros_segmentation  curl  opencv_features2d3  increment  mean  PocoXMLd  boost_log  cv_bridge  roscpp  rotate_recovery  opencv_photo3  SDL  pcl_ros_features  clear_costmap_recovery  opencv_datasets3  rospack  random_numbers  boost_graph  BulletDynamics  iconv  image_rotate  dynamic_reconfigure_config_init_mutex  image_transport  opencv_shape3  octomath  amcl_pf  opencv_flann3  nodelet_math  PocoJSONd  pcl_ros_io  median  rostime  boost_regex  trajectory_planner_ros  message_filters  opencv_videostab3  pcl_ml  PocoFoundationd  global_planner  roslz4  resource_retriever  boost_wserialization  rosconsole  pluginlib  boost_unit_test_framework  opencv_face3  octomap_ros  PocoFoundation  transfer_function  qhullstatic  laser_scan_filters  opencv_stitching3  class_loader  vorbis  urdfdom_model_state  boost_filesystem  geometric_shapes  boost_chrono  boost_serialization  PocoNetd  dwa_local_planner  topic_tools

define include_shlib
$(eval include $$(CLEAR_VARS))
$(eval LOCAL_MODULE := $(1))
$(eval LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $$(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/lib$(1).so)
$(eval include $$(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY))
endef
define include_stlib
$(eval include $$(CLEAR_VARS))
$(eval LOCAL_MODULE := $(1))
$(eval LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../lib/lib$(1).a)
$(eval include $$(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY))
endef

$(foreach stlib,$(stlibs),$(eval $(call include_stlib,$(stlib))))

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := roscpp_android_ndk
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := exceptions
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := $(foreach l,$(stlibs),-l$(l)) -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/3rdparty/lib -ltegra_hal
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(stlibs) c++_static

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/remap/optarLibrary#roscpp).

---

Originally posted by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) with karma: 28 on 2020-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you may use the
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

and you have only json and some web sicket tcp oder udp connection und your done

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) on 2019-11-21**:
is this the de-facto way to go in the cases like mine? we used ros bridge C# implementation in previous project for Unity app, this time wanted to go bare C++ with no WebSocket intermediary...

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-21**:
It is the easy way to get ros connection. With lowest dependecys. You can use a TCP connection without the websockets. Und you Code ist easy Portable from kinetic to melodic.